# Using Rules link to Un/Publish content

Tags: 7, rules, nodes

Have anybody tried this?

Currently I am using [Publish Content](https://drupal.org/project/publishcontent) Module to Un/Publish contents, but the module doesn't support Confirmation action, if somebody hits Publish/Unpublish it just does the action straight away without asking confirmation.

I have been looking for the solution and [Rules Link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) modules advertises it as its promo feature. Being a newbie I am not much aware of [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) power, so, any hint how could I Publish/Unpublish content with this would be very helpful.

So, far I tried by creating new **Link** which displays in my content type, When I click the link it asks for confirmation, but I couldn't figure out how to exactly Publish/Unpublish the content after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved a similar problem with the [Flag](https://drupal.org/project/flag) and [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) modules. I created a flag called 'Published' for nodes and two rules that are activated when content is flagged/unflagged with this flag. These are my settings:

*'Published' flag*

- **Bundles:** Article
- **Display in entity links:** Display link as field
- **Link type:** JavaScript toggle

If you need the flag for (an)other content type(s) too, you simply have to check the box in the flag settings.

*'Published node' rule*

- **Event:** A node has been flagged, under 'Published'
- **Action:** Publish content: Parameter: Content: `[flagged-node]`

*'Unpublished node' rule*

- **Event:** A node has been unflagged, under 'Published'
- **Action:** Unpublish content: Parameter: Content: `[flagged-node]`

If you want to, you can add some extra actions to the rule (e.g. display a message).

Comment: actually this sounds a good solution too, to trigger action/rules when a content is flagged with certain flag.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying this, but when I get to select action, I cannot select anything, it says invalid node and I cannot create any action. Can you guide me, how you did?

Comment: I also tried with flag action, but it supports just one condition, I can unpublish the content but cannot publish back with same action, it creates loop

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope you can solve your problems now.

Comment: thanks... somehow I didn't get that Rules Dropdown selector of fields and then I manually typed node in action, it was showing the error. Now, I manually typed flagged-node as you said, it works.